# visual error with css in angular material table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, angular-material

im trying to on hover of a row the border top and bottom be blue color
but it dosent work
[image: you can see here]

this is my css what am i missing ?

```css
/*loader*/
.loader-box{
  height: 80vh;
}

/*table*/
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.mat-form-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  width:30%;
}
td, th {
  width: 25%;
}
.mat-row .mat-cell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mat-row:hover .mat-cell {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

and this is my html

```html
     <div class="col-md-12 border">
          <div class="text-end mx-1">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
              <mat-label>Buscar</mat-label>
              <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ej. jugo" #input>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            
              <!-- code Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="product_code">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Codigo </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.product_code}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- name Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nombre </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.name}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- price Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Precio </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.price}}$ </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- stock Column -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="stock">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Inventario </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.product_quantity}} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <!-- family Column-->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="family">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Familia </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product"> {{product.family.name}} </td>
              </ng-container>
            
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
              (click)="escribirow(row.id)"></tr>
          
              <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
              <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No encontrado "{{input.value}}"</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
          </div>
        </div>
```

how can i solve this ?
i want the both borders of the same color  im new in front end development
I'm probably forgetting some basic property or something about it, thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using bootstrap framework in your project. Classes col-md-12 and others are specific to bootstrap and I think there are some styles applied to your table element by bootstrap especially to border of `td` element.
Use browser devtools to see if there are extra styles on your td element. Using `!important` in your styles could be one of possible ways to quickly fix this issue.